# Can you schedule emails on Gmail via GmailAPI?

Tags: gmail-api

I was writing some emails and sending them via Gmail API, I was trying to schedule them for the but through the Gmail API but I couldn't find any relevant documentation. Which make me wonder that is that even possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*The Gmail API does not have email scheduling functionality at present.*

#### More Information:

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which requests for this functionality to be exposed via the Gmail API:

- [Expose functionality for creating scheduled emails](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140922183)

Google does seem to know about this already, if it's a feature you would like to see be implemented sooner then I suggest that you hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left of the page, as it lets Google know more people would like to see the featureand so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

#### Workaround:

If you know at which time you would like your emails to be scheduled, and you have already authorised your application, then you can instead run your application using a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for your operating system.

#### References;

[cron - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)