# How to schedule an email using python? Without scheduling the code

Tags: python, email, gmail, schedule, smtplib

As you know, Gmail has a feature for sending emails on a specific date. Although I have found many tutorials about sending emails directly, it seems there is no idea for using the Gmail scheduling feature in python. How we should do it?
**I should note that I do not want to schedule my code and run it at a specific time.**

Comment: 1) [Scheduling an email with the Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55988769/10824407); 2) [Can you schedule emails on Gmail via GmailAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62883011/10824407); 3) [Gmail now supports scheduling emails, how does is work using the gmail rest api, or is the api supporting this feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55915606/10824407). All still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 of these for schedualing tasks.

1. APschedualer: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/ or
2. Celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

The celery is more complex. I recommend you to use the first option.

Comment: I recommend you to not use any of those, but create simple script which send email and set up OS scheduler